# Is there a way to write a glob pattern that matches all files except those in a folder?

Tags: ruby, glob

I need to write a file glob that will match all files except for those that are contained within a certain folder (e.g. all files except those contained within the high level folder `foo/`.

I've arrived at the following glob:

```
!(foo)/**/*
```

However, this glob doesn't seem to match on any files in Ruby's `File.fnmatch` (even with `FNM_PATHNAME` and `FNM_DOTMATCH` set to `true`.

Also, Ruby's glob interpreter seemed to have different behavior than JavaScript's:

[JavaScript glob interpreter](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2F%21%28foo%29%2F%2A%2A%2F%2A&matches=false&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.js&tests=%2Ftest%2Fsome%2Fglobs&tests=%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fsomething.txt) matches all strings

Ruby glob interpreter doesn't match any strings:

```rb
2.6.2 :027 > File.fnmatch("!(foo)/**/*", "hello/world.js")
 => false
2.6.2 :028 > File.fnmatch("!(foo)/**/*", "test/some/globs")
 => false
2.6.2 :029 > File.fnmatch("!(foo)/**/*", "foo/bar/something.txt")
 => false
```

Comment: I do not see a documented negation for [`File::fnmatch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) glob patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use a glob then you can list what is allowed, making it equivalent to the negation:

```rb
extglob = "{[^f]*,f,f[^o]*,fo,fo[^o]*,foo?*}/**/*"

File.fnmatch(extglob, "hello/world.js", File::FNM_EXTGLOB | File::FNM_PATHNAME)
#=> true

File.fnmatch(extglob, "test/some/globs", File::FNM_EXTGLOB | File::FNM_PATHNAME)
#=> true

File.fnmatch(extglob, "foo/bar/something.txt", File::FNM_EXTGLOB | File::FNM_PATHNAME)
#=> false

File.fnmatch(extglob, "food/bar/something.txt", File::FNM_EXTGLOB | File::FNM_PATHNAME)
#=> true
```

`{[^f]*,f,f[^o]*,fo,fo[^o]*,foo?*}` means:

- Any string that doesn't start with `f`
- The strinf `f`
- Any string that starts with `f` and whose second character is **not** a `o`
- The string `fo`
- Any string that starts with `fo` and whose third character is **not** a `o`
- Any string that starts with `foo` if it has at least one more character

---

##### Update

If your string literal is too long it could become a pain to generate a glob that negates it, so why not make a function for it?

```rb
def extglob_neg str
  str.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) do |(_,i),arr|
    arr << "#{str[0,i]}[^#{str[i]}]*"
    arr << str[0..i]
  end.join(',').prepend('{').concat('?*}')
end

extglob_neg "Food"
#=> "{[^F]*,F,F[^o]*,Fo,Fo[^o]*,Foo,Foo[^d]*,Food?*}"
```

***note:** I didn't implement any glob escaping in this function because it seemed a little complicated. I may be wrong though*