# Is there a way to create a Gitlab job CI rule that does not run the job when only if one file was updated?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rules, semantic-release

I am trying to write a gitlab ci job rule that does not run when only `CHANGELOG.md` is committed into the default branch. However, if `CHANGELOG.md` is updated along with other files in the commit, then run the job. Is this possible? Thank you!

The background for this is that I am using the backmerge plugin for semantic-release. If the commit being backmerged is only updating the CHANGELOG.md, then don’t run a pipeline. But if there are other files being backmerged, then do run the pipeline.

For gitlab ci rules, I am struggling to come up with something that does the task.

Comment: This has nothing to do with semantic-versioning and maybe something to do with semantic-release.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#ruleschanges)? A quick scan doesn't indicate a pattern for ignoring changes, so you might have to organize your project tree to allow for triggering on intended content in specified folders. I would try listing the file in rules:changes block with a ! in front of it. Could be a poorly or undocumented feature.

Comment: You could also try listing all the *.ext you do want to trigger on and leave out the md file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use a [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) in order to check if your condition is met:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

run_pipeline:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Running pipeline"
  rules:
    - exists:
        - "*"
      when: always
  before_script:
    - |
      CHANGELOG_UPDATED=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1 | grep -E '^CHANGELOG.md$' | wc -l)
      OTHER_FILES_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1 | grep -v -E '^CHANGELOG.md$' | wc -l)
      if [ "$CHANGELOG_UPDATED" -eq 1 ] && [ "$OTHER_FILES_CHANGED" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Only CHANGELOG.md was updated, skipping the job"
        exit 0
      else
        echo "Other files were updated, running the job"
      fi
```

Here, we use the `rules` keyword with `exists` and `when: always` to ensure that the job runs when any file exists in the repository.

The `before_script` section checks if the `CHANGELOG.md` file was updated and if any other files have been changed in the last commit.

If only the `CHANGELOG.md` file is updated, the script will exit with a status code of 0, causing the job to be skipped.
If other files have been changed, the job will run.

([`rules:changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) is fairly recent, 15.2, and I did not manage to make it work for excluding `CHANGELOG.md` alone)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit odd, but you can make a rule like this:

```yaml
rules:
  changes:
  - '**/{[^C]*,C,C[^H]*,CH,CH[^A]*,CHA,CHA[^N]*,CHAN,CHAN[^G]*,CHANG,CHANG[^E]*,CHANGE,CHANGE[^L]*,CHANGEL,CHANGEL[^O]*,CHANGELO,CHANGELO[^G]*,CHANGELOG,CHANGELOG[^.]*,CHANGELOG.,CHANGELOG.[^m]*,CHANGELOG.m,CHANGELOG.m[^d]*,CHANGELOG.md?*}'
```

And it would have [the intended effect](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2A%2F%7B%5B%5EC%5D%2A%2CC%2CC%5B%5EH%5D%2A%2CCH%2CCH%5B%5EA%5D%2A%2CCHA%2CCHA%5B%5EN%5D%2A%2CCHAN%2CCHAN%5B%5EG%5D%2A%2CCHANG%2CCHANG%5B%5EE%5D%2A%2CCHANGE%2CCHANGE%5B%5EL%5D%2A%2CCHANGEL%2CCHANGEL%5B%5EO%5D%2A%2CCHANGELO%2CCHANGELO%5B%5EG%5D%2A%2CCHANGELOG%2CCHANGELOG%5B%5E.%5D%2A%2CCHANGELOG.%2CCHANGELOG.%5B%5Em%5D%2A%2CCHANGELOG.m%2CCHANGELOG.m%5B%5Ed%5D%2A%2CCHANGELOG.md%3F%2A%7D&matches=false&tests=CHANGELOG.md&tests=anything-else).

This is basically the workaround for the fact that ruby's `fnmatch` (used by `rules:changes:`) does not support the `!` glob metacharacter. Otherwise you could just use the glob pattern `!CHANGELOG.md`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906355/5747944